# Fixed Header width overflow

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/yLt5v/

```
.tc{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

When giving position:fixed for .tc the background is overflown.

How to solve this?

Comment: "How to solve this" solve what..? overflow..? simply don't make it fixed. Why are you trying to make it `fixed`..? please provide proper info.

Comment: add `width: 54.4%;` to `.tc` http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/yLt5v/1/

Comment: It is header... With Language Changing option and some important information. I want it to stay there when scrolling.. adding width 54.4% works.. But how can we get the value.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set percentage and display block

```
.tc{
  position:fixed;
  width:54.5%;
  display:block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7a6hN/)

Answer (score 0):

Assigning an element position:fixed; makes it relative to the BODY element and it will no longer follow the width of the parent element so the width 100% expands it the full width of the page. Now since you have no "left" position declared it will keep alignment after the parent element and the excess width just gets overflown to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Can you solve your problem by adding `left: 0; top: 0;`? Without left the fixed element starts at his own position and have 100% width of viewport.